# Invalid file type returned when posting via PHP Curl

Tags: php, image, post, curl

I am posting an image to an API using CURL. It works perfectly. But when I do the same with php there is some issue that am not able to resolve. I tried setting `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` to `TRUE` in php.ini file.

The API can accept access token both as URL parameter and in header.

```
curl -v -F 'image=@/var/www/devel/id-card-concept.jpg;type=image/jpeg' -F 'title=test upload' -F 'description=test upload description' -H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" "https://api.site.com/v1/uploads"
```

Below is my Php Code:

```
$filename = 'id-card-concept.jpg';
$target_url = "https://api.site.com/v1/uploads?access_token=Access-Token";
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('id-card-concept.jpg');
$post = array('title' => 'Via Api','image'=>'@'.$filename);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

I get the following error:

```
Array ( ) { "message": "Validation failed.", "errors": [ { "attribute": "image", "message": "is an invalid file type" } ] }
```

As per my understanding the image is failing validation.

Comment: What does your packet sniffer show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try change:**

```
$post = array('title' => 'Via Api','image'=>'@'.$filename);
```

**To:**

```
$post = array('title' => 'Via Api','image'=>'@/var/www/devel/'.$filename.';type=image/jpeg');
```

**Or to:**

```
$post = array('title' => 'Via Api','image'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path.$filename.';type=image/jpeg');
```

**See full correct code:**

```
$filename = 'id-card-concept.jpg';
$post = array('title' => 'Via Api','file'=>'@/var/www/devel/'.$filename.';type=image/jpeg');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.site.com/v1/uploads?access_token=cfbf79449f6b71212b3983a49be0056dcb6cd0838c6904bdb9a8f461f9e04220");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

See more on [function.curl-setopt](http://docs.php.net/function.curl-setopt).

Comment: Thanks, the code is not working. Now for some reason its showing a fully themed 404 page. Still not posting.

Comment: 404 file Not Found? Check the page address that is accessing the browser. The code is correct.

Comment: You are correct there was a typo in url. However, I still get the error. `{ "message": "Validation failed.", "errors": [ { "attribute": "image", "message": "is an invalid file type" } ] ` . Could be it related to the file format? In the above curl example in my question I am passing  `;type=image/jpeg` along with the image filename.

Comment: `$post = array('title' => 'Via Api','image'=>'@'.$filename.';type=image/jpeg');` This worked. :) Thanks a lot. I am marking the answer correct. Please update the particular line. You saved my day.